# Is it possible to access node in an electron app without node integration set to true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working with a vanilla electron app. (npx create-electron-app ......)

Is it possible to do `const electron = require("electron");` with `nodeintegration:true`?

Im using a lib that does not support `nodeintegration:true` but my scripts need `nodeintegration:true` to run.

Is there another way to access electron or node without `nodeintegration:true`?

Comment: what do you mean the lib doesn't support node integration true?  We might need more context here. I'm not following the issue

Comment: yes. the lib does not support nodeintergration:true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think you can**
The Better option is to set

```
options = {
    webPreferences: {
         contextIsolation: false, 
         nodeIntegration: true,
         preload: "preload.js" //keep in same path as app.js (or index.js, whatever you use)
    }
};
```

Where, options is the object you use while creating a `BrowserWindow` in electron.

In preload.js (**I assume you want to use a lib called glob**)

```
window.glob = require("glob");
```

Now anywhere in the HTML File (Frontend) you can refer to the lib as `window.glob`